# Google sheets, Live count down of googlefinance "datadelay"

Tags: google-sheets, google-finance

firstly with the googlefinance "datadelay" formula, is telling how many minutes the data will be delay? Can we use that to have a live countdown till data is refresh or not. If that makes sense.

So, I want to show a live time of delay:

- if APPL = 20 (minutes) THEN "data will refresh in 20 minutes" Having count down till refresh.
- THEN if minutes is less than 1, it changes to "minute"
- If there is multiple of data that has different times, like 4 out of 6 data are delayed by 5 (minutes) THEN use the average.
- If there an error, "data may be delay by 20 minutes"

I do not know if it is possible.

Thanks

Comment: Hi! Can you clarify your expected result?  I am so sorry I am having difficulties understanding your requirements. It is better if you are going to provide a sample sheet instead and you can manually input your desired output so the community will have a better chance getting the grasp of it.

Comment: if =googlefinance("AAPL : NASDAQ", "datadelay" = 20, THEN it displays "data will refresh in 20 minutes". Having 20 minutes counting downwards. However, if there are multiple data that are different like data 1 = 20, data 2 = 15 and data 3 = 5, THEN show "data will refresh between 5-20 minutes" (no countdown)/but if possible just average the data, "data will refresh within [average(data)]". IFerror then "data may be delay by 20 minutes"

Comment: I understand now, thank you so much for the clarification about your desired result though, the data delay is coming from this reference document https://www.google.com/googlefinance/disclaimer/ and is based on the Stock Exchanges you select on your Google Finance parameters they are not bound to change. I want to understand that realtime part of your requirements do you still need it or do you just need the nested if statement to handle the data resulting from the formula.

Answer (score 0):

No, I'm afraid it is not possible.